# How does main thread's looper work?

Tags: android

I read about that when looper.loop() method is called it blocks until looper.quit() called.
So how callbacks like activity life cycle method get called? Are they added in the MessagQueue of this looper?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java  should be of interest.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. This is a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right. They are indeed added to the `MessageQueue`.  The looper waits on the `MessageQueue`.

#### Details...

[`Looper.loop()`](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#129) is an infinite loop. As part of this tight loop, the looper waits on the [`next()`](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#142) of its member [`MessageQueue mQueue`](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#74).

The [next()](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java#309) method of `MessageQueue` blocks until it has a `Message`. When a new `Message` arrives, it unblocks. The looper then does some action on the `Message` by calling the [`dispatch() method`](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#164). The UI/ActivityLifeCycle updates are also messages queued to this MessageQueue.  If [`looper.quit()`](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#267) is called, it in-turn calls [`mQueue.quit()`](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java#415). This makes the `mQueue.next()` return a null. When looper.loop() detects a null, it break the tight loop and [returns](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#143).